# ¿Como Se Puede Almacenar Una Imagen En Una Base De Datos SqlLite?

Tags: android

Quiero saber si es posible almacenar una imagen en una base de datos Sql Lite.
Gracias.

Comment: Sí es posible. //Si consideras que este comentario no responde a lo detallado en tu pregunta, considera editarla, agrega lo que has intentado porque la comunidad da la mano cuando vemos que hay esfuerzo de por medio, recuerda que no somos un sustituto de Google. Espero tomes a bien estas letras. Saludos :D

Answer (score 4):

La imagen se guardaría como un arreglo de mapa de bits en un campo que tienes que definirlo como **[BLOB](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)**

para obtener el arreglo de mapa de bits :

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, outputStream);       
byte[] imagenDB = outputStream.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score -1):

Esta [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357668/how-to-store-image-in-sqlite-database) puede que te ayude:

Te recomiendo que siempre que busques dudas de programación te ahorres el buscarlas en castellano.

Comment: Deberías, antes de responder, saber que puede que no sirva el enlace que tu proporcionaste, ya que lo único que se sabe por la etiqueta y el título, es que usa SQLite y Android, pero no sabes que lenguaje (Java, C#), además, no sabes el formato de las imágines. Finalmente sí vas a hacer referencia a algún enlace, sería importante que agregues lo más relevante de dicho link

Comment: Pues tienes razon, intentare ir mejorando.